# flutter ListView scrollController.jumpTo when touched,It doesn't scroll after that

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

flutter ListView scrollController.jumpTo,jumpTo when touched,It doesn't scroll after that.

I see goIdle() in the source code,How can I disarm it. (ScrollPositionWithSingleContext->jumpTo)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsV0i.png)

Comment: please attach your code, not image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.